# How to do relative imports in Python with this structure?

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path

Imagine I have this structure :

```
dir/
   __init__.py
   dir1/
       __init__.py
       x.py
   dir2/
       __init__.py
       y.py
```

Now I want to import x.py to y.py .
I try this `from ..dir1.x import *` in y.py from [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports) but I get this error `Attempted relative import in non-package` .
I search for hours but I can not find any answer to this problem .
There are a lot of similar problems like mine but none of them help me like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) 
Please help .
Thanks a lot .

Comment: In the surface this looks like an exact duplicate of the other question you linked to; you should probably explain why that solution didn't work for you here.

Comment: you are right but if i know what the problem is i don't ask it again . i asks this question again to find the problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `y.py`, add this piece of import code

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
```

then do

```
from dir1.x import *
```

Comment: thanks a lot but what was the first import do ? i think it is work but it isn't clean way to do this .

Comment: @XLichking first import to make sure the parent directory is under the search path of your python, so that it could recognize dir1 as a valid module to import. It doesn't look clean simply because what you asked for is not a natural thing to do in python in the first place.

Comment: thanks a lot but how i could change my structure to be normal ?

Comment: @XLichking you could either reorganize your modules so that submodules don't depend on each other, or you could try to do everything in the root directory, e.g., writing a `main.py` file under `dir` to import `dir1` and `dir2` and doing things there.

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports won't work when files are invocated directly:

```
python y.py
```

since they have `__name__ == '__main__'` instead of their full package name.

For the relative import to work you must use `y` as a package:

```
python -m dir.dir2.y
```

Comment: thanks a lot . but i am new to python . how i could run the last command ? i use windows .

Comment: i use this in cmd in the python folder : python -m c:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\dir\dir2\y   but i get this error : no module named c:\Users\my_user_name\Desktop\dir\dir2\y